# Suppress compiler warning

Tags: c++, g++

C++ how to suppress this warning message when compiling?

Warning:

```
regen.cpp:531:30: warning: 'void* memset(void*, int, size_t)' clearing an object of type 'REGEN' {aka 'struct regen'} with no trivial copy-assignment; use assignment or value-initialization instead [-Wclass-memaccess]
  531 |   memset(&tmp, 0, sizeof(tmp));
```

Code:

```
REGEN tmp;
memset(&tmp, 0, sizeof(tmp));
```

Comment: What is `REGEN`?

Comment: Implement correct constructor? (and so remove `memset` usage).

Comment: The warning is probably protecting you from doing something really bad. What does `REGEN` look like?

Comment: Why is the default constructor inadequate? Why is copy-assignment non-trivial?

Comment: The best way to "suppress" a compiler warning is to address the issue that the warning is about. Sometimes the error message offers suggestions. Can you use assignment instead of `memset`? Can you use value-initialization instead of `memset`? Why not?

Comment: If you have an answer, it belongs in an answer, not in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You must clear your object's data individually within a constructor(or any user-defined init function). Do this:

```
typedef struct regen {
    regen() {
        memset(_someData, 0, 128);
    }
    char _someData[128];
} REGEN;
```

In C++, you must not overwrite the bytes of an object directly like you do in C because unlike C, C++ compiler generates a little more complex low-level information(text/data) from its source. For example, an object of some class/struct may contain an additional data structure called **VTable** for providing runtime polymorphism feature and this data might get corrupted upon performing memset() on the object directly.
As a reference, refer to this documentation of GCC([C++ dialect options(GCC)](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html)). Go to the -Wclass-memaccess section where it mentions the following:

> -Wclass-memaccess (C++ and Objective-C++ only)
> Warn when the destination of a call to a raw memory function such as memset or memcpy is an object of class type, and when writing into such an object might bypass the class non-trivial or deleted constructor or copy assignment, violate const-correctness or encapsulation, or corrupt virtual table pointers. Modifying the representation of such objects may violate invariants maintained by member functions of the class. For example, the call to memset below is undefined because it modifies a non-trivial class object and is, therefore, diagnosed. The safe way to either initialize or clear the storage of objects of such types is by using the appropriate constructor or assignment operator, if one is available.
> std::string str = "abc";
> memset (&str, 0, sizeof str);
> The -Wclass-memaccess option is enabled by -Wall. Explicitly casting the pointer to the class object to void * or to a type that can be safely accessed by the raw memory function suppresses the warning.

I am no C++ god but I hope this helps in some way.

Comment: Your example type has trivial copy assignment, so it might be an over-simplification of the question's `REGEN` type. Whatever stops `REGEN` from having a trivial copy assignment might interfere with your approach. It's tough to provide a useful answer to incomplete questions, which is why many get closed until details and clarifications are added.

Comment: Yes you're absolutely correct. The question should have contained more part of the code. But I just assumed it must have been something like this. But the main point of my answer was to suppress that warning in general sense throughout c++ with a little bit of context on this particular problem. Thats why I referred to the actual documentation too.

Comment: You might want to review [answer]: *"Save yourself some frustration and avoid trying to answer questions which......are unclear or lacking specific details that can uniquely identify the problem."*

Comment: @JaMiT Sure. Thanks for your advice. Anyway I am still new to stackoverflow partication so please don't mind my noobness.